# Power of an adapter working with different input voltages

Tags: power

I have a laptop adapter which, according to its label, works with 100-240 V, 1.8 A, 50-60 Hz as its input. Since only one input current has been mentioned, does it mean that its consuming power is higher in countries with 220-230 V mains electricity than in countries with 110-120 V electricity?

Comment: No, that makes no sense. You might need to look into what the job of a power supply is, and what these markings mean.

Comment: Voltage-current product should remain nearly same under guaranteed supply voltage range. So, if the supply voltage increases then the supply current decreases.